# Get POST from multiple dropdowns in one form

Tags: python, django

Have a form where user can change name on attribut Name and change which attribut a is connected to (attribut b).

Template:

```
"<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="/define_a/{{c.id}}/edit/">
{% csrf_token %}
{% endblock %}

{% block buttons %}
<p><input type="submit" value="Save" />&nbsp;<a href="/define_a/{{c.id}}/">Cancel</a>
</p>
{% endblock %}

{% block a_rows %}
{% for a, a_form in a_list %}
<tr><td><img class="icon" src="{{images_dir}}/delete-icon.png" 
onclick="javascript: return confirmDelete_name('Are you sure? 
This will delete the stuff and all associated information. 
The removal happens immediately and cannot be undone.', '{{a.id}}', 'delete');" />
</td><td>{{a_form.name}}</td>
<td>
<select name= "test">
<option value = "Null">None</option>
<option value = "{{a_form.id}}" selected>{{a.b}}</option>
{% for a, a_form in a_list %}
<option value = "{{a_form.id}}">{{a.name}}</option>
{% endfor %}"
```

View:

Checking that it is a post and that it is valid.

```
 post = [myForm(request.POST, instance = test) for a in a's];
                for p in post :
                    if not new_t.b == p:
                        if p == 'None':
                        new_t.b = None;
                    else:
                       new_t.b = p;
```

But i can't get all the values from the dropdown in the post.
I get all a.name in but only one value from the dropdown, sometimes I don't get any value at all.

Any ideas?

Comment: Please, improve your code formatting. Also, I recomend you to read this [style guide](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/). Sorry for off topic.

Comment: Is this `in a's];` really in your code?

Comment: No i don't have a's in the code. Not my own code. I will look at the style guide.